# How to cause a denial of service on my own local PHP server?

Tags: php, linux, xampp, virtual-machine, denial-of-service

Preface: I am an undergrad Computer Science student about to graduate but I have little to no experience in web development and PHP in particular. Apologies for lack of familiarity.

Background: I am looking to create a simple DoS vulnerability on my own local PHP server which is running XAMPP on a Linux (18.04) 64-bit virtual box machine. In order to ensure I'm not just boosting CPU usage on the virtual machine by local activity, I am running another virtual machine where I use a Python script along with the "requests" library to request the vulnerable page 10,000 times in a loop. As of right now, the vulnerable page (dos.php) runs a loop where it appends a random number to a list and then echo's the hash of a generic text line which are completely unrelated apart from supposedly being CPU intensive.

Issue: I learned that I could output the memory and CPU usage to the browser (via https://devdojo.com/tutorials/how-to-get-memory-and-cpu-usage-in-php). The problem is that I haven't been able to get the CPU usage on the server above about 4%... Memory sits at roughly 30%. However, I know that I am doing some small piece correctly because I am seeing an increase from 0-1% to that number of 4% but nothing beyond that.

The end goal is to demonstrate a proof-of-concept where I show that a fuzzer (SlowFuzz) can find this vulnerability if pointed at the PHP document. Once I have a DoS vulnerability I plan to write a very simple and intentionally broken function. Something like a loop in which the user defines the upper bound.

Here is a picture of the PHP on dos.php:
[PHP Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuUe9.png)

Thank you in advance for your help! Hope this isn't too silly of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Apache can be easily DoS'ed by filling it's request queue with slow reading clients.
Apache has a configured maximum of simultaneously connected clients, and by default does not enforce a minimum read speed to clients, so reading the response at 1 byte/sec would hold the connection open very long and reduce the amount of reconnects needed by your DoS tool while also reducing the chance for a regular client to come through.

Modern Apache setups will drop clients that read too slowly or reject excessive connections from the same address to prevent this kind of attack. I'm not sure if a default XAMPP installation includes this.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I really appreciate the help. However, I'm not sure that this would be a sufficient solution as the essence of the project is CPU-exhaustion Denial-of-Service. So I don't know if that would actually be acting on the CPU.

Comment: CPU bound DoS attacks are becoming more and more difficult as hardware and software get more efficient over time. You're going to have trouble getting it to act up with your O(n) PHP-script. Maybe you can get some higher congestion if you spam requests in parallel (if you aren't already).

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. But the essence of this attack is that only one packet would be required. That's why the parameter such as the upper limit would be the type of intended target. But I can't for the life of me find a way to increase complexity in a way that would actually impact usage. Maybe a hash function with a massive input? Or a series of nested loops? I'm a little bit confused about which functionality has the greatest impact on CPU. If there are forks in PHP could it be a fork bomb? Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: PHP's `posix_fork()` and pthreads are incredibly buggy when called from Apache, you'd have to launch a PHP-CLI script first.